# Where is the Visual Studio 2008 Crash Log?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, logging, plugins, crash, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2008 with SP1 installed and it is crashing when I'm using lambda expressions in the Moq Framework.

At first I thought the problem was Resharper...but now that I have uninstalled it, VS 2008 still crashes. I'm able to replicate the issue every time.

I'm thinking perhaps it may be some other plugin that is causing the issue rather than VS 2008...but I can't be sure of that.

So what I'm trying to find is where Visual Studio logs the crashes that occur?

Unfortunately I'm unable to find it...does anyone out there know if it exists and if so where to look?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you find a solution to your crashes?

Comment: Not entirely. VS still crashes occasionally...sometimes randomly taking out explorer and all running programs with it. However, if I leave Resharper code analysis on while looking at very large (6kLOC+) .cs files it crashes more often. So Resharper may be adding to things.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just a few days ago, I learned about [`devenv.exe`'s `/log` switch](http://blogs.msdn.com/saraford/archive/2008/11/27/did-you-know-there-s-a-way-to-have-visual-studio-log-its-activity-for-troubleshooting-366.aspx). I suggest you give that a try.

Answer (score 1):

The Power Commands add-in was responsible for a similar crash to desktop issue I experianced.

Comment: Thank You! I never would of though this was causing me a lot of problems, now my work project loads every time :) before it would not want to open.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using WinDbg to run an instance of VS, and when it crashes look at managed and unmanaged callstacks.